# 12:00 am as end time is moving to next date

Tags: java, jodatime

Here I am explaining the scenario -

The user, after providing a service has to provide input of the start and end time of the service, but it has to be on the same date. Now when s/he tries to give input like

- `11:45 PM` as start time
- `12:00 AM` as end time

where for example date is: `20/03/12` that means this is a 15 minute service.

The user gets some validation message like "start and end date are not in same date". this is because, whenever s/he is providing `12:00 AM` as *end date*, the system gets that as the starting time of the *next* day.  That's means:

- Start time: `11:45 PM` - `20/03/12`
- End time: `12:00 AM` - `21/03/12`

I am looking for a standard solution, how can this type of situation be handled?
FYI, its in a web application written in [java](/questions/tagged/java).

Comment: Seems that maybe you need to restrict the available times to be from 12:00AM to 11:59PM.  This will ensure that start and end time are always on the same day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well 12:00 am *is* on the next day. Options:

- Check whether the *inclusive* end time is on the same day, by subtracting a millisecond from the *exclusive* end time, and use that for the check
- Explicitly check for midnight

You should think about other situations carefully though, e.g.

- 0 minutes of service, midnight to midnight on the same day
- 24 hours of service, midnight to midnight of the next day
- Attempt at 48 hours of service, midnight to midnight of 2 days later
- "Reversed" times: midnight today to midnight of the previous day

It's also unclear how time zones are going to come into this - bear in mind that in some time zones, midnight won't even *occur* on all days due to DST transitions.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Actually i am looking for a generic solution, what other applications handle this type of problem. Got an idea from you answer. Thanks.
FYI, we consider and apply time zone in our application.